# Animating the React-native-svg

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-svg

I'm trying to animate the SVG by this code:

```
//create animated path component

const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);

  P1 = new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 1});
  P2 = new Animated.ValueXY({x: 1, y: 1});
  P3 = new Animated.ValueXY({x: 2, y: 1});
  path = `M ${this.P1._value} ${this.P1._value} S ${this.P2.x._value} ${this.P2.y._value} ${this.P3.x._value} ${this.P3.y._value}`;

            Animated.timing(this.P1, {
              toValue: {x: 3, y: 3},
              duration: 300,
              useNativeDriver: 'true',
            }).start();


        <Svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 4 4 " fill="blue">
          {/* <Path /> */}
          {console.log('this.P1.x: ', this.P1.x)}
          <AnimatedPath
            d={this.path}
            // d="M 0 1 S 1 1 2 1"
            fill="none"
            stroke="red"
          />
        </Svg>
```

but its not working. Is there anyway to make it animate? 
also should we use the react-native-reanimated2?

Answer (score 3):

Check reanimated2 documentation for [useAnimatedProps](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/useAnimatedProps/#example).
Note that the documented example has some flaws, here is a demo:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
  Animated,
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedProps,
  withTiming
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Svg, { Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);

function App() {
  const radius = useSharedValue(50);

  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    // draw a circle
    const path = `
    M 100, 100
    m -${radius}, 0
    a ${radius},${radius} 0 1,0 ${radius * 2},0
    a ${radius},${radius} 0 1,0 ${-radius * 2},0
    `;
    return {
      d: path
    };
  });

  // attach animated props to an SVG path using animatedProps
  return <Svg><AnimatedPath animatedProps={animatedProps} fill="black" onPress={() => radius.value = withTiming(Math.random() * 180)} /></Svg>
}
```

*I know you probably found a solution but I wanted to provide an answer for people who stumble upon this.*

Comment: I can not find the solution anywhere, but i'll try yours. Thanks

Comment: What are the flaws mentioned? Is it the withTiming hook being inside the onPress handler or?

Comment: I can't remember what I meant with flaws, but this answer was written 2 years ago when reanimated2 was in alpha. The documentation might have mentioned some caveats back then but the current docs don't mention any.

Comment: I implemented this using the Animated from react native. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76667846/13789135

works fine on iOS but gives errors on android. Can anyone please check this